# Share code between platforms/languages (e.g. Swift, Kotlin, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, swift, shared-libraries, kotlin, cross-platform

Applications are often created for three platforms (Web, iOS, Android).

Currently the tech stack we are using are AngularJS (web) and Ionic/Cordova (iOS and Android). Since they are JavaScript based, we are able to write the core business logics (e.g. login) once and then share it across three (I know, it's two) platforms, leaving the UI implementations to the individual platforms. This method is awesome which helps us save so much time and human resources - core business logics are written and tested once and deployed everywhere. [Google](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/11/how-google-inbox-shares-70-of-its-code-across-android-ios-and-the-web/) used similar method to develop Inbox, which allows them to share 70% of the code using [J2Objc](https://github.com/google/j2objc).

We want to apply the same awesomeness to the new era - Swift, Kotlin and a JavaScript based web framework (e.g. React/VueJs). We are open to using any one of these three languages to write the shared code. I am new to Swift and Kotlin but here are my best research results so far:

- [SwiftKotlin](https://github.com/angelolloqui/SwiftKotlin) Converts Swift to Kotlin
- [KotlinJS](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/kotlin-to-javascript/kotlin-to-javascript.html) Converts Kotlin to Js

So the development process would be Swift -> Kotlin -> JavaScript. However, the converted code are not production ready and requires manually editing. Also, the code written has to be language/platform library independent. For example, to write a JSON parser, we use *Codable* protocol in Swift 4, *Moshi* (external lib) in Kotlin and JavaScript can natively manipulate JSON.

I'd like to see if anyone has some nice solution to this question. Or maybe the question is to figure out what can be shared and what has to be done three times. Or this process is taking more time or error-prone and we should write the same logic three different times.

Thanks!

Comment: I would say either stick with the technologies you have now or to manually do all three. I'm not saying the converters you chose are necessarily bad, but it makes it a lot easier to debug in the case of error when you wrote the code yourself natively for each language.

Comment: I've been working for 2 years with J2ObjC. It certainly has some limitations (regarding third party libraries, mainly) but it is quite stable now and allowed us to share more than 60% of our code between Android and iOS. The generated code is not easily readable but can still be debugged in Xcode and does not need manual edition.
We didn't have any web app so there was no need for JS transpilation. However, if you know a good Java to JS transpiler, J2ObjC can be a serious candidate, because as far as I'm concerned it is trustable and production-tested.

Comment: @ClémentMangin Thanks for your input! J2ObjC seems a really good candidate.

Comment: You are far unlikely to be still using Java and Objective-C in 2023. Using an online converter like https://swift2kotlin.com/ could be a good option if you won't want to spend time on building open-source projects.